# Can I run an application with multiple nested jobs in Flink Kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I have got a single jar that uses main function to initiate 3 different jobs (topologies) and I want to deploy it in a kubernetes cluster with flink kubernetes operator (version 1.4) in application mode. I would expect that all 3 jobs to be initiated as I was able to do it using native kubernetes deployment mode ([link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/#deployment-modes)).

Instead only the first job is scheduled from my application, and other jobs are ignored.
The simplified manifest used for FlinkDeployment resource is the following

```yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: my-flink-app
spec:
  image: my-custom-flink-image-with-app
  flinkVersion: v1_16
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "4"
  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 1
    podTemplate:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: task-manager-pod-template
      spec:
        initContainers:
          - name: busybox
            image: busybox:1.35.0
            command: [ 'sh','-c','echo hello from task manager' ]  
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container    
          env:
          - name: FLINK_PARALLELISM  
            value: "2" 
  job:
    jarURI: local:////opt/flink/usrlib/my-app.jar
    parallelism: 2
```

Is this behavior the expected one ? Am I missing something, shouldn't be possible to start a Flink application with multiple jobs using flink-kubernetes-operator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official documentation it is allowed on specific deployment mode.

> Application deployments manage a single job deployment in Application mode while Session deployments manage Flink Session clusters without providing any job management for it. The type of cluster created depends on the spec provided by the user.

[FlinkDeployment spec overview](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/docs/custom-resource/overview/#flinkdeployment-spec-overview)

Answer (score 2):

The Flink Kubernetes Operator expects that each `FlinkDeployment` is a separate Flink application and can be operated (upgraded, savepointed etc.) independently. Please refactor your application into 3 `FlinkDeployments` if you would like to use the Kubernetes Operator.

Comment: Just for clarification it is a single Flink application that it initiates multiple jobs. So what you state is that each job should be deployed as a separate FlinkDeployment correct?